# In pytorch, model randomly trained when using same script and model

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am making a neural network model using pytorch.
I built a simple and shallow 3 layer model by referring to the tutorial.
However, training is random despite using the same model and script.
In other words, it can be seen that the loss does not drop about once out of 4, so it is not trained. I don't know why the model is shallow and unstable. I would be grateful if someone with the same experience as me or who has solved the problem can advise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M50ke.png)
It's same script running result.
1 out of 4 times don't trained.
but I used same script and model.
The value of the input tensor is the same in both the case of learning and the case of not learning.

my script is under here. and x input shape is [10000, 1]

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import sys
import torch
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import re

os.chdir("...")
F1 = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
print(F1)


df = pd.read_excel('10000.xlsx', sheet_name=1)

Ang_tilt = torch.from_numpy(df['Ang_tilt'].values).unsqueeze(dim=1).float()
    
x_list = [Ang_tilt]

nb_epochs = 3000

import sys

#from aug_data_processing import *

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

########################################
####################model

#print(x_list)




net = Net(x_dim=Ang_tilt.size()[1])

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
# optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-9)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-6, momentum=0.7)
losses = []

################forward

for step in range(nb_epochs + 1):
    
    scaler = StandardScaler()

    Ang_tilt = scaler.fit_transform(Ang_tilt)
    Ang_tilt = torch.from_numpy(Ang_tilt).float()
    

    #print(x_list[i])
    prediction = net(Ang_tilt)
    #print(prediction)
    

    loss = criterion(input=prediction, target=y_label)
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    losses.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

#print(Ang_tilt)
plt.title('3_layer_NN_loss_pre+post')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.ylabel('losses')
plt.plot(range(nb_epochs+1), losses)

plt.show()






torch.save(obj=net, f='aug.pt')
```

And this is Network

```
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
import torch

import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
'''
x_dim = dimension을 바로

'''
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, x_dim):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(x_dim, 150)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(150, 100)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100, 40)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(40,1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)

        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc1.weight)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc2.weight)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc3.weight)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc4.weight)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))


        return x
```

Comment: You can standize the features (i.e) `Ang_tilt = scaler.fit_transform(Ang_tilt)` outside the training loop once, Why do you have such a low learning rate `(lr=1e-6)`. And the model will be trained random as the weights are initialized randomly.

Comment: I have to train lot of variables with same model so want to standize inside the loop. and high learning rate don't training well ;( ... Thank you.!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found it by printing my parameters.
When not training, weight is so low.
so I changed model structrue than solved.